# What Determines Which Item Is on Top in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms

So I have a form with a tabcontrol that takes up the entire view. I have 3 buttons that I have managed to get to be on top of this tabcontrol at all times. I have a 4th button that is always underneath the tab control. How do I get always on top like the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that controls, in the same container, appear (both visually and interactively) is determined by their "z-order". The term z-order is referring to the 3rd dimension, depth which is often referred to as the z axis.

In WinForms, the z-order is determined by the order in which controls are added to a ControlsCollection (i.e. Control.Controls).

You can see the z-order of controls (as well as container grouping) by opening up the "Document Outline view" when viewing you Form's designer view. This lists every control and every container. They are indented by their container and the z-order is the order they appear in. You can use the up and down buttons to move the selected item up or down in z-order.

Comment: This worked for a button, but it won't seem to work for a shape.

Comment: @NMunro I'm not familiar with a "shape" control, can you be more specific?

Comment: I added a lineshape from the Visual Basic PowerPack.

Comment: @NMunro looking at the documentation I can see that LineShape inherits Component, not Control. That means it's not a control object and performs its drawing directly to the device context. This would always have a "z-order" (since its not a control it doesn't have a real z-order) below all controls.

Answer (score 2):

Try right mouse clicking the TabControl (not the TabPage) and from the menu, select `Send to Back`